# Should I use 'sample standard deviation' for 'prediction intervals' and 'standard error of the mean' for 'confidence intervals'?

Tags: confidence-interval, predictive-models, prediction, prediction-interval

I just want to make sure I am getting this right. When I am concerned about the "result" of any particular new datapoint I should use *prediction intervals* not *confidence intervals*. When I am concerned about estimating the true population mean then I should use *confidence intervals* and not *prediction intervals*. If you have a lot of data the *confidence intervall* can get very narrow, but the *prediction interval* will stay wide and will represent the uncertainty about any given unlabeled datapoint of the population.

Say we have a population of $M$ datapoints. The extreme would be that you have a sample of all but one datapoint, i.e., the sample size is $N = M-1$ and there is just 1 unknown datapoint. The confidence about the population mean is almost certain and the confidence intervall will be very narrow. However, we have no clue about the remaining unknown datapoint: The prediction intervall will be as wide as for any datapoint. Us having very high confidence about the mean of the population doesn't make us any more certain about a particular datapoint.

For *prediction intervals* this means I should use the *(corrected) sample standard deviation*:

$s = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$

Let's say we're talking about a Gaussian distribution with some confidence level $\alpha$ and a cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the standard normal distribution $\Phi(\cdot)$, such that we can get a z score:

$z = \Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$

... and a prediction interval:

$[\bar{x} - zs, \bar{x} + zs]$

Contrast this with a confidence interval where we use the *standard error of the mean* instead:

$s_{\bar{x}} = \frac{s}{\sqrt{N}}$

Making the confidence interval:

$[\bar{x} - zs_{\bar{x}}, \bar{x} + zs_{\bar{x}}]$

... or for easier comparison to the *prediction interval*:

$[\bar{x} - z\frac{s}{\sqrt{N}}, \bar{x} + z\frac{s}{\sqrt{N}}]$

Am I getting it?

Similar posts, but not quite identical:

- [Standard deviation vs standard error of the mean for intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142228/standard-deviation-vs-standard-error-of-the-mean-for-intervals)
- [Difference between confidence intervals and prediction intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-prediction-intervals)